# Cannot remove app

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I cannot remove an app. In the content site the ellipsis doesn't open anything.

If I try with Powershell, I get app not found.
Does anyone know how to solve this?
Thanks

```
$AppName = "My App"

$appInstance = Get-SPAppInstance -Web "http://mysite" | where-object {$_.Title -eq $AppName}


if ($appInstance -ne $null)
{
Uninstall-SPAppInstance –Identity $appInstance

} else {
Write-Host "app not found"
}
```

Comment: Is the app installed on the my site host?  What does it return if you just run Get-SPAppIstance -Web "http://mysite"?

Comment: The app is on a team site. if from shrapoint powershell I type  Get-SPAppInstance -Web http://mysite I get nothing

Comment: Makes sense - you used "mysite" as a placeholder and I  inferred it was actually My Sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `where {$_.Title -eq '<app_title>'}` insted of `where-object`

Comment: thanks but no luck. How could I list all the apps by the way?

Comment: @Gyonder `$instances = Get-SPAppInstance -Web <URL>`
Maybe try this `Remove-App.ps1 -productId <ProductId> -webAppUrl <webAppUrl>`